# Not able to add all the files to Cloud GIT Repository

Tags: git, google-cloud-platform, maven-2, sbt-assembly

I have a project running on `Spark Scala` at my local. I was able to build it successfully with no issues.

I am facing issues while copying that project to my `git` folder at local itself. It says some of the file names are too long. So I have had to skip those files to accomplish the copy task.

[image]

Well that's not the actual issue I am facing. After copying the project directory to my local git folder when I run:

```
git add spark-pm-cm/
```

I am keeping getting some warning and error messages like:

```
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in spark-pm-cm/null/Coursier/cache/v1/https/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/ipcsocket/ipcsocket/1.0.0/ipcsocket-1.0.0.pom.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory

The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
error: open("spark-pm-cm/null/Coursier/cache/v1/https/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/ivy/ivy/2.3.0-sbt-cb9cc189e9f3af519f9f102e6c5d446488ff6832/.ivy-2.3.0-sbt-cb9cc189e9f3af519f9f102e6c5d446488ff6832.jar.checked"): Filename too long
error: unable to index file 'spark-pm-cm/null/Coursier/cache/v1/https/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/ivy/ivy/2.3.0-sbt-cb9cc189e9f3af519f9f102e6c5d446488ff6832/.ivy-2.3.0-sbt-cb9cc189e9f3af519f9f102e6c5d446488ff6832.jar.checked'
fatal: adding files failed
```

I am trying to push this code to Git repository on Google cloud.

Comment: For Windows you can change the `MAX_PATH` limit: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/maximum-file-path-limitation

Comment: @ John Hanley.. This sounds good not sure whether our admin guys will allow this. I will surely check on this. Thanks

Comment: Another idea is to not commit the Scala cache. You do not need to save those files in the repository.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are a single developer working on a windows machine, and you don't care that git automatically replaces LFs to CRLFs, you can turn this warning off by typing the following in the git command line

`git config core.autocrlf true`

Git has a limit of 4096 characters for a filename, except on Windows when Git is compiled with msys. It uses an older version of the Windows API and there's a limit of 260 characters for a filename.

`git config --system core.longpaths true`

Running these commands as admin in your git bash should do the job !